# Example of an monomial ideal that is weakly reverse lexicographic but not reverse lexicographic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We are looking at a paper titled "Generic Ideals and Moreno-Socias Conjecture" by Edith Aguirre, et al. In the paper they state that an ideal which is reverse lexicographic is also weakly lexicographic. We want to determine whether an ideal can be weakly reverse lexicographic but not reverse lexicographic.

Definition (Graded reverse lexicographic order): Let $\mathbf{x}^\alpha, \mathbf{x}^\beta \in R$ where $R$ is an $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring. Then let $\mathbf{x}^\beta > \mathbf{x}^\alpha$ if $\operatorname{deg} \mathbf{x}^\beta > \operatorname{deg} \mathbf{x}^\alpha$ or if the two degrees equal and the right-most nonzero entry of $\beta - \alpha$ is negative.

Definition: *A minimal generating set* is a set which gives the whole ideal but if anyone of the elements is removed, then it no longer generates the ideal. The elements are called *minimal generators.*

Definition: A monomial ideal $J \subset R$ is *weakly reverse lexicographic* if whenever $\mathbf{x}^\beta$ is a minimal generator of $J$, then every monomial of the same degree which precedes $\mathbf{x}^\beta$ in the reverse lexicographic term order must be in $J$. We say that $J$ is *reverse lexicographic* if all the conditions above are satisfied but $\mathbf{x}^\beta$ is any monomial, not necessarily a minimal generator.

We've looked at many examples and have yet to find an example. We've been using a correspondence between $(m,n) \longleftrightarrow x^m y^n$ and studying these monomials in the Euclidean plane.

Any help or hints are appreciated. Thank you in advance.